# Separating items by type

Tags: javascript

How can I separate the items based on the item type? I have an item types code which are 'Rental Pallet' and 'Board'. As you can see on the data array there are some object/items that have the same item type code. I want to separate them by their item type code, if the 'Rental Pallet' item type code is MORE THAN ONE within the `items` array then it should be separate into a new array and if the item type code is 'Board' then it should also separate into new array. I'm using JavaScript to manipulate the data. See the data and my desired output below.

**Code:**

```
itemTypes = data.flatMap((d) => [...new Set(d.items.map(item => item.itemType))]);

items = data.flatMap((d) => {
  return itemTypes.map((type) => {
    return {
      code: d.code,
      supplierId: d.supplierId,
      paymentTermId: d.paymentTermId,
      purchaseRequestId: d.purchaseRequestId,
      items: d.items.filter(item => item.itemType === type)
    }
  })
});
```

**This is the sample data array:**

```
const data = [
  {
    code: "FD",
    supplierId: 1,
    paymentTermId: 69,
    purchaseRequestId: 1,
    items: [
      {
        itemCode: "Item 1",
        itemType: "Rental Pallet",
        purchase_request_item_id: 1,
      },
      {
        itemCode: "Item 2",
        itemType: "Rental Pallet",
        purchase_request_item_id: 2,
      },
      {
        itemCode: "Topboard 1",
        itemType: "Board",
        purchase_request_item_id: 3,
      },
      {
        itemCode: "Topboard 2",
        itemType: "Board",
        purchase_request_item_id: 4,
      }
      {
        itemCode: "Bottomboard 2",
        itemType: "Board",
        purchase_request_item_id: 5,
      }
    ],
  }
];
```

**Current Output:**

```
[
  {
    code: "FD",
    supplierId: 1,
    paymentTermId: 69,
    purchaseRequestId: 1,
    items: [
      {
        itemCode: "Item 1",
        itemType: "Rental Pallet",
        purchase_request_item_id: 1,
      },
      {
        itemCode: "Item 2",
        itemType: "Rental Pallet",
        purchase_request_item_id: 2,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    code: "FD",
    supplierId: 1,
    paymentTermId: 69,
    purchaseRequestId: 1,
    items: [
      {
        itemCode: "Topboard 1",
        itemType: "Board",
        purchase_request_item_id: 3,
      },
      {
        itemCode: "Topboard 2",
        itemType: "Board",
        purchase_request_item_id: 4,
      }
      {
        itemCode: "Bottomboard 2",
        itemType: "Board",
        purchase_request_item_id: 5,
      }
    ],
  }
];
```

**Output should look like this:**

```
[
  {
    code: "FD",
    supplierId: 1,
    paymentTermId: 69,
    purchaseRequestId: 1,
    items: [
      {
        itemCode: "Item 1",
        itemType: "Rental Pallet",
        purchase_request_item_id: 1,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    code: "FD",
    supplierId: 1,
    paymentTermId: 69,
    purchaseRequestId: 1,
    items: [
      {
        itemCode: "Item 2",
        itemType: "Rental Pallet",
        purchase_request_item_id: 2,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    code: "FD",
    supplierId: 1,
    paymentTermId: 69,
    purchaseRequestId: 1,
    items: [
      {
        itemCode: "Topboard 1",
        itemType: "Board",
        purchase_request_item_id: 3,
      },
      {
        itemCode: "Topboard 2",
        itemType: "Board",
        purchase_request_item_id: 4,
      }
      {
        itemCode: "Bottomboard 2",
        itemType: "Board",
        purchase_request_item_id: 5,
      }
    ],
  }
];
```